# const корректность для указателей

Tags: c++, классы

```
class InnerTest
{
public:
    InnerTest() {};
    ~InnerTest() {};

    void some_non_const_method() { std::cout << ++m_data << std::endl; }

private:
    int m_data{ 0 };
};

class Test
{
public:
    Test() {};
    ~Test() {};

    // error C2662: 'void InnerTest::some_non_const_method(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const InnerTest' to 'InnerTest &'
    void foo() const { m_test.some_non_const_method(); };

    void bar() const { m_ptest->some_non_const_method(); };

private:
    InnerTest m_test;
    std::unique_ptr<InnerTest> m_ptest{ std::make_unique<InnerTest>() };
};

int main()
{
    Test t1;

    t1.foo();
    t1.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Итак есть примерно такой код, как можно добиться const корректности при использовании указателей для константных методов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В С++ const корректность не подразумевает транзитивности, т.е. const применяется только к самому объекту (указателю), но не распространяется на объекты, на которые тот указывает. А умные указатели из стандартной библиотеки просто мимикрируют поведением обычных указателей. Однако несложно реализовать обертку, имитирующую транзитивное поведение, для этого следует лишь добавить соотв. const перегрузки:
[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/VWG8hA)

```
template< typename x_Value > class
t_TransitivePtr
{
    private: x_Value * m_p_value;

    public: explicit t_TransitivePtr(x_Value * p_value): m_p_value{p_value} {}

    public: x_Value & operator * (void) { return *m_p_value; }

    public: x_Value const & operator * (void) const { return *m_p_value; }

    public: x_Value * operator -> (void) { return m_p_value; }

    public: x_Value const * operator -> (void) const { return m_p_value; }
};

#include <string>

class
t_Test
{
    private: t_TransitivePtr<::std::string> m_ptr;

    public: explicit t_Test(::std::string & value): m_ptr{&value} {}

    public: void Method(void) { m_ptr->clear(); } // OK

    public: void ConstMethod(void) const { m_ptr->clear(); } // Error
};
```

В разных других языках может быть реализовано другое поведением. Например в языке D const полностью транзитивный; это подразумевает, что const указатель в принципе не может указывать на не const объект.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже написал схожую обёртку, но решение показалось громоздким и не совсем очевидным, подумал, что может есть что-то проще. Буду думать как реализовать в проекте

Comment: почему вы больше не VTT ?)

Answer (score 3):

Компилятор прав - у вас член имеет тип

```
unique_ptr<InnerTest>
```

и его значение вы не меняете. Если вы хотите явно указать, что там у вас константный указатель - то скажите об этом прямо:

```
unique_ptr<const InnerTest>
```

Все, вообще-то корректно - `const` в функции-члене относится к объекту класса, так что `m_test`, *входящий в объект класса*, действительно не может вызывать неконстантный метод. Но какой-то левый, не пойми где находящийся объект `InnerTest` - с какой стати ему запрещать вызывать неконстантный метод?...

Comment: компилятор безусловно прав, класс ничего не знает про указатель. но всё же можно получить от указателя такое же поведение как и от обычного члена класса, чтобы в константных методах было нельзя вызывать неконстантные методы объекта по указателю, но сохранить возможность их вызова в неконстантных методах?